# Duplicate column is not updating. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to insert data into MySQL and update the column if there is a duplicate of the column.
my sql query is :

```
INSERT INTO domain_pricing (tld, provider, year_1, year_2, year_3, year_5, year_10,
  renew_1, renew_2, renew_3, renew_5, renew_10) 
VALUES ("tickets", "namecheap", 29567.2, 59134.4, 88701.6, 147836, 295672, 
  29567.2, 59134.4, 88701.6, 147836, 295672) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  tld='tickets', provider='namecheap', year_1=29567.2, year_3=59134.4,
  year_5=88701.6, year_10=147836, renew_1=295672, renew_2=29567.2, renew_3=59134.4, 
  renew_5=88701.6, renew_10=147836
```

Comment: You should run `SHOW CREATE TABLE domain_pricing` and include the result, so we can see if you have a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY constraint in the table definition.

Comment: Thank you, Solved I forgot to add the unique key.